# Has anyone noticed that probably about 50-60% of all questions/answers are all made by EXTREMELY new people?

Tags: support

You can pretty much go to any page and find at least one answer/question made by a person with 1 reputation and no badges. Examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image one](https://superuser.com/questions/458786/how-to-disable-context-menu-shadow-in-kde-4)

[image two (the bottom answer)](https://superuser.com/questions/166654/microsoft-word-excel-2003-how-to-have-sequential-numbers-keep-writing-themselv)

[image three](https://superuser.com/questions/458785/convert-data-from-columns-to-rows-without-loosing-already-stored-data-below)

[image four](https://superuser.com/questions/458794/good-nas-for-backup)

[image five](https://superuser.com/questions/458730/keep-ssh-port-forwarding-connection-alive) (top answer)

[image six](https://superuser.com/questions/458761/accurately-cut-video-files-from-command-line)

[image seven](https://superuser.com/questions/458756/how-to-capture-session-name-into-tmux-variable)

I'm not saying they're bad, a lot of the questions are good. I"m just curious if there's some glitch resetting (or showing) 1 reputation. Because I think it **may** be a bug, I'm tagging bug.

I found all of these posts on the front page.

Comment: Well, can't you open their profiles and see if it's realistic? How many answers did they give? How many upvotes did they receive?

Comment: That's not a bug, but a feature

Comment: [Some public analytics data](http://www.quantcast.com/superuser.com). Trend goes up. New users arrive all the time.

Comment: Woohoo, show some love for the [/review/first-answers](http://superuser.com/review/first-answers) queue. `</advertising>`

Comment: @slhck you need to fire your PR person, that is the coolest feature ever, never heard of it before now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a bug, but a feature. We get an average of 200 new users a day and 160 questions/day.

Its to be expected that a large portion of them will be asking questions. Couple that with the fact that 90+% of our traffic comes through Google, that means its actually very **unlikely** a question is being asked by an existing user.

So no its definitely not a bug. We're here to help people, whether they are new or not. They only thing to worry about is the quality of the questions

Comment: Well said, I was just putting it here to make sure nothing was wrong.